# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar un documento después de hacer populate en Mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, populate

Estoy tratando de hacer una búsqueda avanzada que me permita filtrar por nombre del Tablero (mi modelo), y por una propiedad que hace referencia a otro modelo. El modelo es el siguiente:

```
const tablero_Schema = new Schema({
  contrato: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Contrato',
    required: true
  },
   nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, { collection: 'tableros', timestamps: true })
```

Siendo "contrato" una referencia a un modelo muy extenso del cuál solo necesito 'contrato' (el nombre del contrato) y 'centro_costos' (siendo un código con el cuál facilitan la búsqueda). Hasta el momento solo me funciona con nombres y cuando intento con un contrato no funciona, me trae un array vacío

El método que estoy intentando es:

```
  Tablero.find({
    $or: [{ nombre: { $regex: key, $options: "i" } }]
    // { 'contrato.centro_costos': { $regex: key, $options: "i" } },
    // { 'contrato.contrato': { $regex: key, $options: "i" } 
  }).populate('contrato', {
    match: {
      $or: [{ 'centro_costos': { $regex: key, $options: "i" } },
      { 'contrato': { $regex: key, $options: "i" } }]
    }
  }).then(tableros => {
    console.log(tableros)
  })
```

Comment: ¿Puedes aclarar el tipo de dato de los campos implicados en el `populate` y el valor que tomaría `key`? Entiendo que has encontrado ya una forma de hacerlo, pero la misma no es óptima de cara a la atomicidad de las operaciones de búsqueda. Saludos

Comment: Centro_costos y contrato (los datos que vienen del populate a contrato) son cadenas de caracteres. Contrato es el nombre del contrato y centro_costos es el código a dónde se hacen el cargo transaccional en el banco a cada contrato. Key sería el valor que se le envíe por medio del request.params y este depende de lo que se busque para filtrar

Comment: Inclusive la palabra `key` la cambié por `query`

Comment: Vale, en cuanto pueda te doy una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Cualquier otra duda la responderé ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const tableros = await Tablero.find({ nombre: RegExp(query, 'i') })
  const contratos = await Contrato.find({ $and: [{ $or: [{ centro_costos: RegExp(query, 'i') }, { contrato: RegExp(query, 'i') }] }, { Estado: 'Abierto' }] }, { _id: 1 })
  if (contratos.length > 0) {
    let contratos_id = contratos.map(c => ({ contrato: c._id }))
    const tableros = await Tablero.find({ $or: contratos_id })
  }
```

Con el uso del await, ver la siguiente referencia que explica el uso del await y del async, callback y promise [más información](https://deskevinmendez.medium.com/callbacks-async-await-y-promises-en-javascript-d3d82c9f500a), pude almacenar todos los documentos de la colección "contrato" sin necesidad de usar el populate, es una solución adaptable y entendible que encontré. No sé a nivel de eficencia en calidad de tiempo si habrá otra más rápida pero aún estoy nuevo en mongoose.

Con las RegExp hago que busque una palabra que coincida y que no sea exacta en la colección. RegExp funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
let query = "Contrato"

RegExp(query,'i').
```

Siendo 'i' que coincidan mayúsculas y minúsculas.

'Estado' en el query de Contrato.find hace que solo me traiga los contratos en estado abierto, $and para que se cumplan las condiciones de $or y estado. $or es para que se cumplan en el query una de las condiciones

Answer (score 0):

Puede agregar un middleware que se ejecute antes de la búsqueda en su modelo tablero, que apunte a contrato y seleccionar solo los campos que necesite.

```
const tablero_Schema = new Schema({
 contrato: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Contrato',
   required: true
 },
 nombre: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 }
}, { collection: 'tableros', timestamps: true })

// middleware pre 
// /^find/ reguex -> this.find(), this.findOne(), ...
tablero_Schema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'contrato',
    select: 'contrato centro_costos',
  });
  next();
});
```

Comment: Y como haría para usar ese hook? Porque necesito esa info para seguir haciendo búsquedas anidadas a otros dos modelos más que tienen como referencia ese tablero

Comment: ¿Si ya colocó ese middleware en su modelo, ya reviso los datos que obtiene al realizar alguna consulta al tablero? Ya no necesitaría realizar ningún populate para obtener los datos que necesita (contrato y centro_costos). Este populate se ejecutaría automáticamente al consultar Tablero.find(), Tablero.findOne(), ...